# Slide to left ul li via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-animate

I have this structure:

```
<div style="background-color:#FFF;height:49px;border-top:1px solid #ef4723;clear:both">
  <div id="marka-slider" class="row">
    <ul>
      <?php if (($references = Reference::getAll())) :
              foreach ($references as $r) :
      ?>
        <li>
          <img src="<?php echo Reference::getUploadPath() . '/' . $r->mediapath; ?>"
               alt="<?php echo $r->title; ?>" title="<?php echo $r->title; ?>"/>
               <!-- <?php CVarDumper::dump(array('ref: ' => $r->attributes), 5, 1); ?>  -->
        </li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var slider;
$(document).ready(function () {
  slider = $('#marka-slider ul li');

  setTimeout(function() {
    bgscroll('right');
  }, 1000);
});

function bgscroll(direction) {
  var sign;
    if (direction === 'left') {
      slider.stop().animate({'background-position': '+=10000'}, 200000, 'linear', bgscroll);
    } else {
      slider.stop().animate({'background-position': '-=10000'}, 200000, 'linear', bgscroll);
    }
```

But it isn't working. When I check via Firebug, it doesn't give a error. How can I solve it?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xpVRT/)

Comment: did you try to slide the images??

Comment: @Charlie yes.i try it

Comment: please give me definatin of class row used in div

Comment: your bgscroll function does not have closing braces

Comment: you didnt include CSS in you demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xpVRT/2/

You were animating background image of the `li` tag, while the images were inside `li` in the `img` tags.